# WebGL 2.0 unsigned integer input variable

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, webgl2

I've been trying to point an `Uint32Array` buffer to a `uint` input variable.

All the information I can find online says that it should be possible, yet I get the same error no matter what I do:

```
[.WebGL-0x62401b7e200] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Vertex shader input type does not match the type of the bound vertex attribute.
```

Here's my vertex shader:

```
#version 300 es
in vec4 a_ipos;
in uint a_cdata;
uniform vec2 ures;

void main() {
    uint x = a_cdata & 0x7C00u;
    uint y = a_cdata & 0x03E0u;
    uint z = a_cdata & 0x001Fu;

    vec4 pos = a_ipos + vec4(float(x), float(y), float(z), 1.);

    gl_Position = vec4(pos.x * ures.y / ures.x, pos.yzw);
}
```

And here's my call to webgl to point the buffer to the attribute:

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, chunkBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint32Array(chunkData), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(cdataloc);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    cdataloc,
    1,
    gl.UNSIGNED_INT,
    false,
    0,
    0
);
```

It seems `gl.UNSIGNED_INT` is not the same type as `uint`.
However the [GLSL 300 ES reference card](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles3-quick-reference-card.pdf) says that it's a 32-bit unsigned integer.
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/vertexAttribPointer) agrees that `gl.UNSIGNED_INT` is 32-bit unsigned integer.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I've tried using `gl.INT` and `in int ...` and still nothing. Changing the precision of the integers to `highp` also doesn't change anything. (provided `highp` would convert integers to 32-bit, which doesn't seem to be the case).

Changing the type to float does work. But any other type I use doesn't.

I also tried using `gl.SHORT`. This is to discard the theory that the `int` type in glsl might be 16-bit integer. Still the same error.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874983): WebGL: How to Use Integer Attributes in GLSL

Doesn't solve my issue. As the documentation the answer provides is outdated. GLSL 1.00 ES doesn't allow integers in attributes as per [specification](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf).

However, [GLSL 3.00 ES specification](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.pdf) doesn't seem to care as long as the type is not one of the following: `boolean`, `opaque`, `array`, `struct`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of a classic mistake. The data `type` in [`vertexAttribPointer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/vertexAttribPointer) refers to the data type in the array itself (or more in the buffer).

It does not refer to the data type of the attribute in the shader.
When you use [`vertexAttribPointer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/vertexAttribPointer) the data is (still) converted into floats. You can use `normalized` to control if it gets normalized or not, but it's still converted into floats.

What you're actually looking for is [`vertexAttribIPointer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL2RenderingContext/vertexAttribIPointer) (notice the **I** for **I**nteger.)

```js
vertexAttribPointer()
//          ^ No I so Float
vertexAttribIPointer()
//          ^ I for Integer
```

The docs for [`vertexAttribPointer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/vertexAttribPointer) also mention it under [Integer attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/vertexAttribPointer#integer_attributes):

> **Integer attributes**
>
> While the `ArrayBuffer` can be filled with both integers and floats, the attributes will always be converted to a float when they are sent to the vertex shader. If you need to use integers in your vertex shader code, you can either cast the float back to an integer in the vertex shader (e.g. `(int) floatNumber`), or use [`gl.vertexAttribIPointer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL2RenderingContext/vertexAttribIPointer) from WebGL2.

---

You can also read more about it in the [spec under "Uniforms and Attributes"](https://registry.khronos.org/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/#3.7.8).

Comment: I haven't tried to see if this fixes my issue. If it does I'll mark it as the answer. However, if true. WHAT THE F. JUST HOW IN THE DEEPEST PIT OF HELL DOES SOMEONE THINKS THAT ADDING 2 FUNCTIONS THAT LOOK IDENTICAL AT A GLANCE YET DO 2 VERY DIFFERENT THINGS WAS A GOOD IDEA?

Thank you for your time finding the solution to my problem.

Comment: Actually now that I'm reading the docs in MDN. Those docs on the `vertexAttribPointer` are wrong then. I'm going to report it to mozilla.

Comment: You're welcome! Based on the error and the code snippet, then I'm confident in saying this is your issue. However, feel free to comment, if it doesn't resolve it. But yeah, like I said, this is a very classic mistake. Even the newer OpenGL API "suffers" from it, having `glVertexAttribFormat()` and `glVertexAttribIFormat()` or even more confusing `glVertexArrayAttribFormat()` and `glVertexArrayAttribIFormat()` if you use DSA

Comment: Which part of the Mozilla docs do you think is wrong? Using an integer data `type` for `vertexAttribPointer()` is perfectly valid, as long as you want it to be reinterpreted as a float. I just realize now, that the Mozilla docs also mention it, down at [Integer attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/vertexAttribPointer#integer_attributes) (I updated the answer to include the quote)